# Listbox with thousand of images in a wrappanel

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, ui-virtualization

I'm trying to create a listbox that may contain over a thousand images in a grid like design. In term of design it would be quite similar to this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7URQD.jpg]

Since I can't use a wrappanel as that would break UI virtualization and a stackpanel can't list images in such a grid(?), I'm trying to solve this issue using a modified version of https://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com

My XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="GameWheel" ItemsSource="{Binding GameData}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <c:VirtualizingWrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Name="GameImage" Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" Width="{Binding ElementName=GameWheel, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource widthConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

While this approach works, it's still quite slow and buggy, especially when using bind on the image width. Is there a better way of archiving the same result? Without the custom wrappanel preferably.

Comment: Are all items going to be the same Width (and height)?

Comment: I set the same width on all, but some might have a different height.... (I don't have control over the images itself). However, for now I limit the width so I always get 5 images on a row.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my implementation of [VirtualizingWrapPanel](https://github.com/CoryCharlton/CCSWE-Libraries/blob/master/Source/WPF/Windows/Controls/VirtualizingWrapPanel.cs). Also available (with more included) from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CCSWE.WPF/).

This code originally came from this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75847/Virtualizing-WrapPanel) article which mostly worked and appears to be the same place you started. Along the way I fixed several bugs and improved performance so it might help you as well.

**Update:** The key is going to be to bind to the `VirtualizingWrapPanel.ItemWidth` rather than `Image.Width`. There was a bug in both implementations of the `VirtualizingWrapPanel` that would prevent the children from being resized if the `ItemHeight` or `ItemWidth` values changed. I fixed this bug in this [commit](https://github.com/CoryCharlton/CCSWE-Libraries/commit/19f3dc526a0b955ab3df330d6167dfcfa2d31375) (line 358).

Admittedly it's a brute force fix but I wanted to get something checked in for you and have to head out. I tested it with 10,000 images and it was very snappy. I'll work on a better solution (ie: only remeasure when we know the value has changed) and update this answer when I do.

**Update 2:** Quick change to improve the child.Measure with this [commit](https://github.com/CoryCharlton/CCSWE-Libraries/commit/d423aa5651c1a4aca23e3afe4b66c897ddad8ced).

```
//TODO: If either child Height or Width == PositiveInfinity and the other side == ChildSlotSize then we probably don't need to measure. Need to test this
if (!child.DesiredSize.Equals(ChildSlotSize))
{
    child.Measure(ChildSlotSize);
}
```

Still room for improvement but no time for proper testing right now and this works.

Comment: Thank you. I also based my version on that codeproject post. However, adding a width (binding it to the size of the screen) sadly adds 5-10 seconds before the WPF page containing this control is loaded. Settings a fixed width is way faster, but sadly doesn't scale with the size of the screen.

Comment: @NeoID maybe try setting the binding on the `ItemWidth` property of the `VirtualizingWrapPanel` and setting the `Image` to fill the available space?

Comment: Tried that as well. Changed the `VirtualizingWrapPanel` to `<c:VirtualizingWrapPanel ItemWidth="{Binding ElementName=GameWheel, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource widthConverter}}" IsItemsHost="True" />` but then all images disappear. Setting a fixed width works. I guess something funny is going on width the binding, just not sure what as it works everywhere else in my code. It just divides the width on 5.

Comment: @NeoID See my updated answer with bug fix and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I can confirm that using itemwidth on the VirtualizingWrapPanel now works! Thank you!

However, the speed remains the same. About 5 seconds for 6k images @50KB.

Comment: Interesting. I'm seeing sub-second time on my test project that is loading 10,000 images @1MB. All my images are coming from a local folder. In any case I just ran a Perfomance Explorer Profiler on the project and 39.1% of that time was spent executing the `child.Measure(childSlotSize)` function that comes from the PresentationFramework. If you remove the binding to `ItemWidth` the performance improves? If possible can you profile the code to see what is going on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88232/discussion-between-cory-charlton-and-neoid).

Comment: Using this virtualizedWrapPanel inside an ItemsControl doesn't work. I believe the scroller is null